# Algebraic manipulation of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been asked to integrate $\int Ae^{at} dt$ and I know that the integral is $\frac Aae^{at} + c$.

Although this is simple it goes against my understanding that $\int a^{n}  da = \frac a{n+1}^{n+1} + c$

I would therefore assume that $\int Ae^{at} dt= \frac A{a+1}e^{(a+1)t}+ c$ and $\neq \frac Aae^{at} + c$

Please can someone help me to understand the error in my logic? I am very new to this topic so would appreciate it if an explanation is laid out in simple terms.

Comment: In neither case did you write the _variable_ of integration - try doing that and you should see the difference between the two.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the constant term is this what you mean?

Comment: No; I mean the variable being integrated _over_.  When we talk about the integral of a function, it's the integral with respect to some variable — just like when we talk about the derivative of a function, it's the derivative with respect to some variable. What variables do you think the integrals here are with respect to?

Comment: I have added the variable it has been integrated over but still unsure as to why the method I mentioned above is not used, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the indefinite integrals involved in the discussion:

$$
\int Ae^{at}\, dt=\frac{A}{a}e^{at}+C,\quad (a\neq 0);\tag{1}
$$

$$
\int a^n\, da=\frac{1}{n+1}a^{n+1}+C,\quad (n\neq -1).\tag{2}
$$

In (1), $a$ is a **constant** while in (2), $a$ is a **variable** of the function $f(a)=a^n$.

You should not apply (2) when calculating $\int Ae^{at}\, dt$.

---

The symbol $\int f(x)\,dx$, by definition, gives a family of *[antiderivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)* to the function $f(x)$. Whatever one gets on the right of the identity
$$
\int f(x)\, dx=F(x),
$$
one must have that $F'(x)=f(x)$.

When context is clear, one sometimes omits the symbol $dx$ and simply write $\int f(x)$ (which is a bad idea though). Here "context is clear" means one knows exactly what is the *variable* for the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, how can you tell that the $a$ is a constant but the $n$ is a variable?

Comment: @FlewittConnor: Because that's the only way the right hand side would be the correct solution to the left. See also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals#Rational_functions

Comment: When you write an integral, the $ dx $ or $ dt $ or $d$ whatever is there precisely to specify the variable

Comment: By the way, I suspect you confused yourself by treating $a$ as a constant in your first example and a variable.in your second.  Using the same letter (say, $x$) for your "variable" for both examples will shed some more light on this for you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ and so by the chain rule, the derivative of $e^{ax}$ with respect to $x$ is $ae^{ax}$. So the integral of $e^{ax}$ is simply $\dfrac{e^{ax}}{a}$. This is just a very simple version of the reverse chain rule. On the other hand, the derivative of $a^n$ with respect to $a$ is $na^{n-1}$ (by the power rule) and so $\displaystyle\int a^n da = \dfrac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$. This uses the reverse power rule. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: Typo: $dx$, not $dn$ in the integral for $a^n$.

Comment: @Jack I was mixing up my derivatives. whoops

Comment: Yeah it's $\ln n\cdot a^n$.